# Cannot use macro in C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, c-preprocessor, gnu

I'm trying to build the following code in Eclipse CDT on Linux with GNU:

log_defs.h

```
#pragma once

#define dbg_log(fmt, ...) debug_logger::debug(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, fmt, __VA_ARGS__, 0)
```

ErrorMessage.cpp

```
ErrorMessage::ErrorMessage( void ){ dbg_log( L"ErrorMessage::ErrorMessage _in" ); }

ErrorMessage::~ErrorMessage( void ){ dbg_log( L"ErrorMessage::~ErrorMessage _in" ); }
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
../sources/ErrorMessage.cpp: In constructor ‘ErrorMessage::ErrorMessage()’:
/include/log_defs.h:27:97: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
 #define dbg_log(fmt, ...) debug_logger::debug(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, fmt, __VA_ARGS__, 0)
                                                                                             ^
../sources/ErrorMessage.cpp:150:37: note: in expansion of macro ‘dbg_log’
 ErrorMessage::ErrorMessage( void ){ dbg_log( L"ErrorMessage::ErrorMessage _in" ); }
                                 ^
../sources/ErrorMessage.cpp: In destructor ‘ErrorMessage::~ErrorMessage()’:
/include/log_defs.h:27:97: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
 #define dbg_log(fmt, ...) debug_logger::debug(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, fmt, __VA_ARGS__, 0)
                                                                                             ^
../sources/ErrorMessage.cpp:152:38: note: in expansion of macro ‘dbg_log’
 ErrorMessage::~ErrorMessage( void ){ dbg_log( L"ErrorMessage::~ErrorMessage _in" ); }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is that when you don't pass any additional arguments to the macro, `__VA_ARGS__` expands to nothing. You therefore end up with the following code like this after macro expansion:

```
debug_logger::debug("SomeFile", "SomeFunction", 42, L"TheFormatString", , 0)
```

If the code you've posted faithfully captures your real scenario, the way out is easy: subsume `fmt` into the variadic part:

```
#define dbg_log(...) debug_logger::debug(__FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__, 0)
```

That way, you'll always pass at least one argument (the `fmt` string) to the macro, and the commas will work out nicely.